# How to compare 2 list by characters content and its correspondents double values?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have 2 lists: a string list and a double list with same length and with same index of correspondence. I need to compare all the strings, find the indexes of the list that has the same characters, independent of its order, and delete the highest double value that corresponds to both,

***Example:***

```
List<string> str= new List<string>();
str.add("efc");
str.add("abc");
str.add("cde");
str.add("cab");
str.add("fbc");

List<double> vlr= new List<double>();
vlr.add(0.1);
vlr.add(0.5);
vlr.add(0.4);
vlr.add(0.2);
vlr.add(0.3);
```

and this case, "abc" => (0.5) must be deleted because "cab" has the same characters AND lower correspondent value =>(0.2).

There is a lambda expression for this 2 arrays??

What I've tried:

```
var distinct = list .Select((str, idx) => new { Str = str, Idx = idx }) 
.GroupBy(pair => new HashSet<char>(pair.Str), HashSet<char>.CreateSetComparer()) 
.Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(p => p.Idx).First()) 
.ToList();
```

Comment: Do you really mean "delete the highest double value when 2 strings have the same value", or do you perhaps mean "replace the double value for a string when an attempt to add a larger double value occurs"? The latter is s simple filter on `Add` operations, while the former requires some internal knowledge of the data structure to be efficient.

Comment: Sounds like homework?  What have you tried?

Comment: hahaha, it's not homework, I was using one list of string `var distinct = list .Select((str, idx) => new { Str = str, Idx = idx }) .GroupBy(pair => new HashSet<char>(pair.Str), HashSet<char>.CreateSetComparer()) .Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(p => p.Idx).First()) .ToList();`  but I don´t know how link the double list toghether!!

Comment: odd, somebody else asked THE EXACT SAME QUESTION: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553478/comparing-dictionary-key-by-characters-and-values

Comment: I decide to ask again, I will delete the other!

Comment: Actually it was the same person who asked the same question in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newDict = str.Zip(vlr, (s, d) => new { s, d })
                .GroupBy(x => String.Join("", x.s.OrderBy(y => y)))
                .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.d).First())
                .ToDictionary(x => x.s, x => x.d);
```

Comment: the orginal issue has 2 arrays: a string array and a double array with same lenght and with same index of correspondence. In this case, is possible to use lambda expression with 2 separate arrays?

Comment: @user1801745 Yes, just replace the `list` in answer with `strings.Zip(doubles, (s, d) => new KeyValuePair<string, double>(s, d))`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to solve it:

```
// Pair the strings with their correspondence values
var pairs = str.Zip(vlr, (s, d) => new {s, d});

// Group using a sorted string, eliminating differences due to character order
var groups = pairs.GroupBy(x => new string(x.s.ToCharArray().OrderBy(c => c).ToArray()));

// For each group, retain the item with the lowest correspondence value 
var filtered = groups.Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.d).First().s);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code:

```
    var group = str.GroupBy(s => string.Join("", s.ToCharArray().OrderBy(c => c)));
    var _vlr = group.Select(g => g.Min(s => vlr[str.IndexOf(s)]));
    var _str = group.Select(g => g.OrderBy(s => vlr[str.IndexOf(s)]).First());
```

and the result:
[image]

Comment: I get a error with this code when have more then 65 items on a list.... other suggestion?

Comment: I used QtX answer [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628157/comparing-2-list-by-characters-content-and-its-correspondents-double-values) and changed jarvanJiang code: `var group = listNome.GroupBy(s => string.Join("", s.Split('-').OrderBy(y => y)));
                    var _vlr = group.Select(g => g.Min(s => listDist[listNome.IndexOf(s)]));
                    var _str = group.Select(g => g.OrderBy(s => listDist[listNome.IndexOf(s)]).First());` and BINGO!